# how to subtract/filter particular branch from git-show-branch?

Tags: git, branch

I tried looking into the git glob'ing feature but couldn't find what I want to do.  I have many branch off of master that are relatively close to each other but master is way far behind so when I do git show-branch, the tree is extremely tall so I want to basically filter out master.  I need something like git show-branch * - master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all <commit>..
```

which will graphically show all branches and commits after `<commit>`.  Instead of the `--all` argument you could list up branches using:

```
git log --graph --oneline <commit>.. <path> ...
```

and if these don't get you a shorter output you might try:

```
git branch | grep -v master | xargs git log --graph --oneline <commit>..
```